# Use multiple proc sql or just 1 to join 3 tables to 1 table?

Tags: sas, left-join, proc-sql

I have a large table `A`, with around 5M observations and want to join it with 3 other tables with around 400k observations each.

The tables will be joined using different keys to A.
All tables have just 1 occurrence of the joining keys only, so they will be one to one joins

Is it more efficient to use just 1 `proc sql` block to make the 3 joins on `A` or write 3 separate `proc sql` blocks to make 1 join each?

Comment: What are the sizes and number of observations of the tables? Are they indexed on the relevant (foreign) keys? are the tables sorted and how? Did you consider a sollution with hash tables in a datastep too?

Comment: The main table has around 5M entries and the tables to be joined have around 400K rows each. The tables to be joined are sorted on the joining(foreign) key.

Answer (score 0):

The only richt answer to your question is: It does not matter.

In contrast to many other procedures and to the `data` step, `proc sql` does not wait for a `run` statement to execute: each sql statement is executed individually as if it were in a separate `proc sql`.

However, you can do a lot to improve your performance by creating indexes on the keys in the 3 smaller tables. (Google `sas sql "create index"`) before joining them.

After that, it might be benificial to do all joins at once:

```
select <whatever you need>
from A
left join B on B.key1 = A.key1
left join C on C.key2 = A.key2
left join D on D.key3 = A.key3;
```

because then, you only read and write the big table once.